# Update donut chart using the c3 library (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, d3.js, c3

I need to update a donut chart using the `c3` library. The chart is created by the following code:

```
function (datapie) {   
    var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#idpiechart',
    color: {
        pattern: Colors,
    },
    data: {               
        columns: datapie,
        type: 'pie',
    });
}
```

Now I just need to update this chart from another function, I'm using the `load` method but this does not work:

```
function(updatedata){
    var pie = $("#idpiechart");            
    pie.load({
        columns: updatedata
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a D3 selection? `var pie = d3.select("#idpiechart");`

Answer (score 4):

Looking at this [sample code](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_pie.html), you need to call update on the `chart` object returned from `c3.generate`:

```
var chart = null;
function (datapie) {   
    chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#idpiechart',
      color: {
        pattern: Colors,
      },
      data: {               
        columns: datapie,
        type: 'pie',
    });
}

function(updatedata){        
    chart.load({
        columns: updatedata
    });
}
```